# Why doesn't nginx like my $args?

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I have a WordPress site located at `mysite.com/blog`, the files of which are located in `/var/www/mysite/wordpress`. Why, when I visit `mysite.com/blog/test`, does my nested location block only get hit if I remove `$args` from `try_files`?

```
server {
    server_name mysite.com;

    location /blog {
        alias /var/www/mysite/wordpress;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php$args;

        location ~ \.php {
            # This is only reached if I remove $args from try_files
            return 401; # For testing purposes 
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the associated error in the log:

`"/usr/share/nginx/html/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you forgot the `?` between `index.php` and `$args`. The convenience variable `$is_args` contains a `?` when necessary, and is empty when there was no query string.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php$is_args$args;
```

Of course, with WordPress you do not need to use `$args` at all, as it gets the query string elsewhere:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;
```

is sufficient.

It appears you are using `try_files` with `alias` directive. That's a [long standing bug](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) in nginx, use `root` directive instead.