# How can I get around using alias in nginx?

Tags: nginx, wordpress

Due to a [long-standing bug](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) in nginx I was [advised](https://serverfault.com/a/642558/69948) to switch my alias directive with a root directive. Unfortunately this now breaks my static files, which are located in a different directory to my site path (`mysite.com/blog` -> `/var/www/mysite/wordpress`). How can I get around this, without changing my static file structure? Here's my full location block:

```
location /blog {
    root /var/www/mysite/wordpress;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(?:\/blog\/)(.+\.php)(.*);
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rewrite the URI :

```
location /blog {

    root /var/www/mysite/wordpress;
    rewrite ^/blog/([^.]+\.[^.]+)$ /$1 break;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(?:\/blog\/)(.+\.php)(.*);
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

}
```

This will remove the `/blog` part of the URI for URIs containing a potential file suffix in it (`something.something`).

Comment: I've noticed this doesn't work with a file with multiple periods (e.g. style.main.css). Is there any way of simplifying this? I'm thinking something along the lines of `rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ /$1 break;`.

Comment: @Jonathan Multiple periods seems a weird way of naming files to me. You can use `rewrite ^/blog/(.*\.[^.]+)$ /$1 break;` if you can't change file names.

Comment: `.min.css` and `.min.js` is a fairly standard convention for minified files (take a look at StackOverflow's source!). I ended up going with `^/blog/(.+)$ /$1 break;` for the sake of simplicity. Many thanks again.

Comment: @Jonathan Didn't say it was not commonly used. Still, I prefer subfolders. Personal opinion :)

Comment: Fair enough... :)

Comment: I searched google about 2 hours for this. Thank you!